# What defines a single organism?

Tags: taxonomy, classification, prokaryotic-cells

I suppose what prompts me to ask this question is my wondering if it is possible to have a multicellular prokaryotic organism. For instance, can a biofilm be considered a single organism? Why or why not?

Why is it that multicellular prokaryotes do not exist (if they do not)?

At what point can a collection of cells be considered one whole -- do they need to all share identical DNA?

Fire away.

Comment: What defines a single organism is ongoing debate in biology. It will probably never be answered because it is a human attempt to create discreet categorizes for something that exists in a continuous spectrum.  Because there is a lot of gray area, generally when dealing with an edge case an author will say what definition they are using.

Comment: I agree with John. See [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.730.5098&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for an example of a discussion of issues and proposed definitions. I don't necessarily agree with the proposed definitions, but I think the article does an ok job of pointing to some literature for further discussion.